Spring-loaded retractable roll screen magnet
This spring-loaded retractable roll screen for our front door has too much tension for the magnetic latch to hold the screen in place - it immediately is pulled away from the magnet. What would the repair options be?


is the spring adjustable

Mechanical latch, stronger magnet, additional magnets, find a spring tension adjustment screw, ...

All of the things @keshlam mentioned, plus: check that the magnet actually touches the metal when closed. From the picture, it looks as if the screw heads stick out too far, preventing the latch from engaging.

Where would any tensioner be? On the end of the roll, requiring full removal to access? Of, assuming these vanishing screens work like rolldown shades but vertically mounted, one would have to unwind them a few turns to lower tension. The magnet is certainly no neodymium. Thanks for responses

You need a bigger/stronger magnet.
I have used this Magnetic latch to keep a pantry door closed. It works very well.  ( you can spray it bronze.)
